# While Printing HTML page font size change in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I tried to Print the content of the page using window.Print() function, font size is changed while printing from Firefox and IE.

I have also used the @media query for Print as below:

```
@media print {
    .print-body-txt {
        font-size: 1.125em;  
        font-size-adjust:0.5;
    }
}
```

I have tired font-size in px, pt and em

Comment: Copy paste failure with `@@media print`?

Comment: Why `@@media` (repeated "@")?

Comment: `@@media` two @ could be the problem. Use `@media`

Comment: Actually, My code is in ASP.NET MVC(Razor engine), so two @ are required.

Comment: Your final stylesheet contains this repeated char too?

Comment: No, final stylesheet didn't contain it. I'll modify question to avoid confusion